# Syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm a complete BASH beginner who needs to make sure this script works. It's supposed to restore an evenstore backup from an azure blob storage. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

When I run it in ShellCheck:

```
Line 14:
export AZURE_STORAGE_KEY=<Insert key>
^-- SC1009 (info): The mentioned syntax error was in this simple command.
       ^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this variable assignment. Fix to allow more checks.
                          ^-- SC1072 (error): Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

When I actually run it :

```
restore_eventstore.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
restore_eventstore.sh: line 14: `export AZURE_STORAGE_KEY=<Insert key>'
```

I have googled these errors but I was unable to find an answer for my case. Any help appreciated. Here is the script in its entirety:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Needs azure cli to work.
# Install command: curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash

backup_name=$1

if [ -z "$backup_name" ]
then
    echo "Must supply an file to use in the restore"
    exit
fi

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=stoclbackups
export AZURE_STORAGE_KEY=<Insert key>

echo "Downloading backup $backup_name from blob storage"
az storage blob download --container-name node1backups --name $backup_name --file $backup_name

if [ ! -s "$backup_name" ]
then
    echo "Failed to download the backup file $backup_name"
    exit
fi

echo "Stopping the eventstore service"
systemctl stop eventstore

if [ -d eventstore_backup ]
then
    echo "Removing old local eventstore backup"
    rm -rf eventstore_backup
fi
echo "Doing an backup of the current db to eventstore_backup"
mkdir eventstore_backup
cp -r db/* eventstore_backup

echo "Removing the old data from eventstore db directory"
rm -rf db/*

echo "Unpacking the backup $backup_name into the eventstore db directory"
tar -zvxf $backup_name -C db/

echo "Truncate the eventstore data to the latest chaser checkpoint"
cp db/chaser.chk db/truncate.chk

echo "Restore is complete. Start the eventstore service with: sudo systemctl start eventstore"
```

Comment: Does your script contain the literal string `<Insert key>`, or did you replace it with an actual key string?

Comment: @steeldriver, that's indeed what their error message looks like. The trailing `>` is missing the filename to redirect to, hence the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value used for `AZURE_STORAGE_KEY` is a place-holder text string saying `<Insert Key>` . This needs to be replaced with an actual key for the Azure Storage Account.